# Obtain clear and recent image from Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, google

### How can I obtain images as clear as the default Earth Engine map satellite view for analysis of a given area?

I am implementing a project to monitor a transmission line corridor using earth engine and AI. I have tried viewing the corridor in Earth Engine's satellite view and there is a clear enough resolution. I took this image from Google Earth PRO

[image: Sample image with the transmission line marked red.]

*The above image is dated 2015*

I want to build an application that receives recent images which are about 1 or 2 months old to monitor the transmission line corridor and a specified buffer around it. I have already got the tower locations in a KMZ file.

The problem occurs when I used datasets from Sentinel 2 or Landsat 8 the image or layer appears pixelated or blurry. How can I obtain pictures as clear as (or clearer than) the default map satellite view for analysis of a given area in an application?

*I do not know if this is also due to my location (Africa, Ghana, Accra). Sometimes some of the examples seem clearer over the USA.*

Some of the recent images also had clouds obscuring the view so for test purposes I tried one of the default examples, doing a cloud mask over an area of Accra and received pixelated images.
[image: Result of the Sentinel 2 cloud mask example over the University of Ghana]

*Result of the Sentinel 2 cloud mask example over the University of Ghana.*

The code that produced this layer (taken from the default examples)

```
// This example uses the Sentinel-2 QA band to cloud mask
// the collection.the collection is also pre-filtered by the
// CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE flag, to use only relatively
// cloud-free granule.
// Function to mask clouds using the Sentinel-2 QA band.
function maskS2clouds(image) {
  var qa = image.select('QA60')
  // Bits 10 and 11 are clouds and cirrus, respectively.
  var cloudBitMask = 1 << 10;
  var cirrusBitMask = 1 << 11;
  var mask = qa.bitwiseAnd(cloudBitMask).eq(0).and(
         qa.bitwiseAnd(cirrusBitMask).eq(0))
  // Return the masked and scaled data, without the QA bands.
  return image.updateMask(mask).divide(10000)
  .select("B.*")
  .copyProperties(image, ["system:time_start"])
}
// Map the function over one year of data and take the median.
// Load Sentinel-2 TOA reflectance data.
var collection = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2')
.filterDate('2016-01-01', '2016-12-31')
// Pre-filter to get less cloudy granules.
.filter(ee.Filter.lt('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE', 20))
.map(maskS2clouds)

var composite = collection.median()

// Display the results.
Map.addLayer(composite, {bands: ['B4', 'B3', 'B2'], min: 0,             max: 0.3}, 'RGB Clouds')
```

**TLDR**: How can I obtain a recent image/ image collection with a resolution as clear as the default map satellite view?

---

Am I doing this right?

Answer (score 1):

Export.image.toDrive({
image: composite,
description: '**add_your_image_tittle_without_spaces**',
scale: 30,
region: **the one you asked for**
});

try this or try to change the palette for clearer images.

Comment: Thanks for answering. However I realised the image resolution was still poor, sometimes gray or even black or pixelated when zoomed in(landsat8 and Sentinel 2). So I guess I have to fix the poor resolution problem first. If you know a way to get suitable resolution closd to the satellite view you can suggest that here too. (Even if it's outside earth engine)